# Internal structure of TLP250

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, powermosfet

Does anyone know what is the internal structure of TLP250? Like how the connections are done inside the IC?

Comment: What's wrong with the diagram in the datasheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complementary emitter follower gives much more current gain using the secondary supply and inversely lower source impedance V/I=Zout from the opto current-source CTR ( equivalent to low hFE) suitable for the TLP250 to drive a  MOSFET and IGBT rather than the open collector type Optos.

Answer (score 2):

Mosfet Driver TLP 250  . This image found by a quick search on the internet.[image]